# How to read NotMapped properties in EF 5?

Tags: linq, webforms, entity-framework-5, asp.net-4.5

I can not figure out how to access a property that is marked as NotMapped so I can print it. When I try to access it I get

> The specified type member 'LinkAddress' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

my LINQ query is:

```
(from n in db.Navigation
                                  join s in db.Sections on n.SectionID equals s.SectionID
                                  join sl in db.Locale_Sections on s.SectionID equals sl.SectionID
                                  where n.Category == "Books" && sl.CultureID == 1
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      s.LinkAddress,
                                      sl.Title,
                                  }).ToList();
```

my context for Section is:

```
    [Table("Section")]
public class Section
{
    [Key, Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int16 SectionID { get; set; }

    public Int64 LogoFileID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LogoFileID")]
    public virtual File File { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(15), Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string RouteName { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(15), Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Locale_Section> Translations { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string LinkAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return Type + "/" + RouteName;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is not mapped it cannot be used in a query... you have to materialise the object before you can access the property...

```
var materialised = (from n in db.Navigation
     join s in db.Sections on n.SectionID equals s.SectionID
     join sl in db.Locale_Sections on s.SectionID equals sl.SectionID
     where n.Category == "Books" && sl.CultureID == 1
     select new
     {
          s,
          sl.Title,
     }).ToList()

// This bit is done in CLR
return materialised.Select(m => new 
{
    m.s.LinkAddress,
    m.Title
});
```

Alternatively you can bring your logic into the query which is valid...

```
(from n in db.Navigation
 join s in db.Sections on n.SectionID equals s.SectionID
 join sl in db.Locale_Sections on s.SectionID equals sl.SectionID
 where n.Category == "Books" && sl.CultureID == 1
 select new
 {
     LinkAddress = s.Type + "/" + s.RouteName,
     sl.Title,
 }).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks I whent with your alt solution since it is less code and cleaner to read.